# C# stringbuilder double code

Tags: c#

I am trying to write this line into stringbuilder

```
param = param + "listener=" + textBox3.Text.Trim() + "&";
```

as

```
sb.AppendLine("param = param + "listener=" + textBox3.Text.Trim() + "&";");
```

The thing is that I am writing a class using csharpcodeprovider and I want to add lines to stringbuilder.

Comment: could you tell us what error?

Comment: I think this is not the right way to add in stringbuilder, I am missing something

Comment: Well the code highlighting shown above might show you some of the problem with it.

Comment: It's the right way of adding it, it's what you're trying to add that's the problem - why have you wrapped your original statement in quotes?  What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: You are looking for `sb.AppendLine("listener=" + textBox3.Text.Trim() + "&");`.

Comment: Things would be easier for you if you didn't work against the core concept of StringBuilder: Use `.Append()` and `.AppendFormat()` or pass a `string.Format()`into `.AppendLine()`. Do not concat string parameters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to escape double quotes with `\` so that `"` will not be the borders of string.

```
sb.AppendLine("param = param + \"listener = \" + textBox3.Text.Trim() + \" & \";");
```

You have to make your question clear. If you want to change that line of code with using `StringBuilder`.

```
sb.AppendLine("listener=" + textBox3.Text.Trim() + "&");
```

Comment: OP is not trying to put `param = ...` in the string builder. He is rewriting existing code, but does it wrong. It should be `sb.AppendLine("listener=" + textBox3.Text.Trim() + "&");`.

Comment: @PatrickHofman - how do you know? OP just says "I am trying to write this line into stringbuilder". This solution writes that line into a stringbuilder.

Comment: By some magic, the author of this answer could understand this question. Now, after this answer it sounds logical - the OP just wants to display the string, but he can't do this because of quotes. There are no calculations or assignments - it looks like the question was as simple as **"how to output a string containing quotes"**.

Answer (score 4):

You should use it like this:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(param);
sb.AppendFormat(" listener={0}&", textBox3.Text.Trim());
```

first append `param` and then use `AppendFormat` to add `textBox3.Text`. You should not join strings using `+` formatting them using `AppendFormat` is better way (because one string is created, not multiple)

Comment: Even shorter in C# 6.0: `sb.Append($" listener={textBox3.Text.Trim()}&")`.

Comment: Steering OP away from concatenating string parameters of StringBuilder methods is the best answer by far.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev great example :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use double quote marks as escape characters and your code should look like this:

```
sb.AppendLine("param = param + ""listener="" + textBox3.Text.Trim() + ""&"";");
```

Comment: well in that case you are right, although it isn't really explicit what he is trying to achieve

Answer (score 2):

You misplaced and missed `"` .

Convert this

```
("param = param + "listener=" + textBox3.Text.Trim() + "&";")
```

to this

```
("param ="+ param + "listener=" + textBox3.Text.Trim() + "&")
```